# How to get a <a> tag using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I'm writing a simple scraper with Ruby using Nokogiri.

```
def processNokogiri

  doc = HTTParty.get("https://www.remotelyawesomejobs.com/jobs")
  @parse_page ||= Nokogiri::HTML(doc)
  @jobs = @parse_page.css(".job").first.at_css "h2"
  puts '*********************'
  puts  @jobs
  puts '*********************'
  flash[:error] = "Noko"

end
```

When I print  `@jobs`, the console shows me:

```
<h2>
<a itemprop="title" href="/jobs/the-coral-project-mozilla-infrastructure-integration-engineer">Infrastructure &amp; Integration Engineer</a>
<span class="company">
at
<span itemprop="hiringOrganization">The Coral Project @ Mozilla</span>
</span>
</h2>
```

I want to access

```
href="/jobs/the-coral-project-mozilla-infrastructure-integration-engineer"
```

and the name of the Company: "The Coral Project @ Mozilla"

How can I filter `@jobs` entity to access this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@parse_page.css(".job").first.at_css("h2 .company span").text #=> "The Coral Project @ Mozilla"
@parse_page.css(".job").first.at_css("h2 a")['href'] #=> "/jobs/the-coral-project-mozilla-infrastructure-integration-engineer"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy! Works perfectly

Comment: Don't use `css('some_selector').first`. Instead use one of the `at` variants.